# What is the difference between wala and soot?

Tags: java, control-flow-graph, soot, inria-spoon, wala

I need to chose a framework for following tasks in Java:

- extract control flow graph
- interprocedural and intraprocedural analysis
- dataflow analysis
- PDG
- different souce code analysis tasks (like method body extraction, test code extraction)

Which framework would be a good fit for my tasks?

I came across so many different tools apart from wala, soot as well like JavaParser, Spoon, to name a few.

Which framework should I chose? Ideally I would like to adopt a tool that is easier to use. Additionally, my expectation was given the popularity of Java tools should already exist for all these tasks. Or my understanding is wrong?

I will appreciate it if anyone please point me to different resources etc.

Comment: JavaParser and Spoon are for Java **source** code; Soot is for Java byte code (source code parsing unmaintained for years). The others I am not sure.

Comment: @JMax Unfortunately, you are not right on Soot not being maintained for years. Please check its GitHub page (https://github.com/soot-oss/soot). You might have been confused when the time it was developed/maintained in McGill. Currently, it's maintained by the University of Paderborn.

Comment: @Ekin I was talking about the part of Soot that reads Java source. The part that reads/writes Java or Android byte code is still maintained, but the part that reads Java source code is more or less unusable.

Answer (score 1):

Spoon would be a good fit for many tasks on your list, and it is quite easy to use. It is primarily used for source code transformation and analysis with the official documentation at [http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/](https://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/). For control and data flow analysis there is the [spoon-control-flow](https://github.com/INRIA/spoon/tree/master/spoon-control-flow) package which is based on Spoon.

Comment: are you aware of tools that support slicing? I see https://github.com/little8hwq/javaslicer though very old and supports very old jdk (java 7). Would be interested to know whether you are aware of any tools/library available?

Answer (score 1):

I used Soot many times, for different things. I am 100% sure that Soot extracts control-flow graphs, and performs intraprocedural and dataflow analysis. They really do have a good community and good people who are willing to help you out. However, I am not quite sure if you can extract PDG or SDG with Soot. I read papers that claim they did it with Soot, but there are no source codes or examples that I was able to find (maybe you have to do some modification, I don't know). But I also do know that you can perform an [interprocedural analysis with Soot](https://www.bodden.de/pubs/bodden12inter-procedural.pdf) as well.

Here are some [tutorials for Soot](https://github.com/soot-oss/soot/wiki/Tutorials). If you have any questions I recommend you to join their mail group and ask questions if you have any.

For WALA, I was also in a need of a PDG since that in its wiki it says you can extract a PDGs. Even though when you import the WALA project there are some example codes in it that you might want to look at. However, I was never able to get it running, because there wasn't enough documentation. Most of its documentation is pretty old.

Here are some [tutorials for WALA](https://github.com/wala/WALA/wiki/Tutorials).
Here is also a [dataflow analysis test case](https://github.com/wala/WALA/blob/3e1a81fdc05773923e104ea4a55fdddb10965539/com.ibm.wala.core/src/test/java/com/ibm/wala/examples/analysis/dataflow/DataflowTest.java) code that they have. Maybe it can give you some insight. I strongly recommend you to look into their test cases, it might help.

Briefly, I believe you can all of the things you asked with Soot and WALA. However, personally, I was mostly able to do them with Soot. I guess it is more of a matter of how familiar get with them and how much you like one of them.

Comment: are you familiar with any working code example to do interprocedural analysis with Soot? You referred to a paper here.

Comment: You might want to check this repository https://github.com/rohanpadhye/vasco . It is again based on another paper named "Interprocedural data flow analysis in Soot using value contexts". It is not a huge project, so I believe it can be easy to understand. You might find some examples in the code. For inter-procedural analysis you might need "heroes" as a dependency, but it seems these guys didn't use it.

Comment: You might also find some simple and useful code examples of Soot from here as well. https://www.brics.dk/SootGuide/sootsurvivorsguideexamples.tar.gz